# What does GLFW require linking with?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, glfw, static-linking, undefined-reference

I keep getting undefined reference errors trying to compile this code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I have the files test.cpp(the source file) and libglfw3.a(downloaded from the [glfw website](https://www.glfw.org/download.html)) on the same folder, while GLFW/glfw3.h is inside the same file as the other c++ headers like iostream, vector, etc...

I can generate the .o file just fine:

```
g++ -c test.cpp
```

And that gives me test.o, but when I try to link it with the libs like this:

```
g++ test.o libglfw3.a -lopengl32 -o test.exe
```

I get these errors:

```
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What else am I supposed to be linking those files with, is there something wrong with my code, what am I missing here?

Edit: Okay, now I tried using the 64 bit pre compiled binaries instead of the 32 bit, and now I get this:

```
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/init.obj):(.text$mn+0x73): undefined reference to `__imp___stdio_common_vsprintf'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/init.obj):(.text$mn+0x327): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/init.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwInputError]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x196): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x82): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x91): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x9b): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x206): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.text$mn+0x45): more undefined references to `__security_check_cookie' follow
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPollMonitorsWin32]+0x20): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwSetVideoModeWin32]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformGetMonitorPos]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformGetMonitorWorkarea]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformGetVideoModes]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_monitor.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformGetVideoMode]+0x14): more undefined references to `__GSHandlerCheck' follow
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.text$mn+0xe7): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.text$mn+0x97): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.text$mn+0xbc): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.text$mn+0x3bc): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.text$mn+0x1d2): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.text$mn+0x48): more undefined references to `__security_check_cookie' follow
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwIsWindowsVersionOrGreaterWin32]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwIsWindows10BuildOrGreaterWin32]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwInputErrorWin32]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'    
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwUpdateKeyNamesWin32]+0x20): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformInit]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'        
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_init.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$loadLibraries]+0x8): more undefined references to `__GSHandlerCheck' follow
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/window.obj):(.text$mn+0x29e): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/window.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glfwCreateWindow]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/input.obj):(.text$mn+0x286): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/input.obj):(.text$mn+0x794): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/input.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glfwUpdateGamepadMappings]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'     
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/input.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$parseMapping]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/context.obj):(.text$mn+0x594): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwRefreshContextAttribs]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck' 
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/egl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x4b7): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/egl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x49): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/egl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x534): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/egl_context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwInitEGL]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/egl_context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwCreateContextEGL]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x447): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x2d): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x6c): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x3a3): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x77f): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwInitWGL]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwCreateContextWGL]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wgl_context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$choosePixelFormat]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'      
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x50): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x1a7): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x50): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x225): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x84): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x3ee): more undefined references to `__security_check_cookie' follow
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformSetWindowPos]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformGetWindowSize]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformSetWindowSize]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformSetWindowSizeLimits]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformSetWindowAspectRatio]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformGetFramebufferSize]+0xc): more undefined references to `__GSHandlerCheck' follow
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.text$mn+0x1d3): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.text$mn+0x10e): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.text$mn+0x233): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.text$mn+0x38e): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.text$mn+0x60): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.text$mn+0x518): more undefined references to `__security_check_cookie' follow       
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwInitJoysticksWin32]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwDetectJoystickConnectionWin32]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwDetectJoystickDisconnectionWin32]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformPollJoystick]+0x28): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwPlatformUpdateGamepadGUID]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_joystick.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$deviceObjectCallback]+0x10): more undefined references to `__GSHandlerCheck' follow
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/osmesa_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x21b): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/osmesa_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x4c): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/osmesa_context.obj):(.text$mn+0x1cd): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/osmesa_context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwInitOSMesa]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'      
glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/osmesa_context.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glfwCreateContextOSMesa]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I this sort of means that I am making progress, because now the functions are defined, whatever they use is missing. Still doesn't using the 64 bit libs mean that the .exe file will not work in a 32 bit system?

Comment: Tools exist to show symbols exported by libraries, so it's quite possible for you to find out what exports the symbols you need. Read up on `nm`, `objdump`, `readelf`, `ldd` and more..

Comment: Also remember that the *order* you link things in matters. You should link objects that *need* a symbol before objects that *provide* the symbol. Since most linkers will process objects in the order given and throw out any symbols provided by the current object (as unneeded) if it has not previously seen anyone needing it.

Comment: Based on GLFW documentation, it mentioned that you need to explicitly link with gdi32 library (When using MinGW to link an application with the static version of GLFW, you must also explicitly link with gdi32).  https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_win32

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but instead of `libglfw3.a` you would normally use `-L. -lglfw3`.

Comment: The second set of errors looks like you're using binaries built for visual studio (`.lib`), not for MinGW (`.a`).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That was exactly what I needed to fix, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You try to link glfw library in a wrong way. The correct command is:

```
 g++ test.cpp -lopengl32 -lglfw3dll
```

This works only if glfw files are properly placed in MinGW folders. Make sure that

glfwf3dll.a file is placed in `MinGW/lib`,

glfw3.dll in `MinGW/bin`,

and GLFW folder with headers inside `MinGW/include`.

---

Otherwise, if you really want to use static GLFW library (.a), which will be placed in the same folder as your project, paste libglfw3dll.a to the project folder and compile the following way:

```
 g++ test.cpp -lopengl32 libglfw3dll.a
```